# How can I infer a circuit topology only from measuring/controlling its input and output?

Tags: signal-theory, circuit-theory

Let's have a circuit only composed of resistors connected in a given topology. This topology (network) has a well defined boundary (input/output connectors) but otherwise we don't know how it is connected internally. We can perform all sort of experiments on the input/output (for example: connect them to other circuits). This is a thought experiment, in principle we do not have time/resources/practical limitations (for instance, the resistors doesn't burn).

Is it possible to infer the internal topology in this conditions? What kind of measurements are the more informative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Any matrix of resistors has a certain transfer charcteristics between input and output, and can only attenuate the input signal.

You can only observe the transfer parameters how test signals on input affects the output, and how varying output load affects the input current.

The problem is, these transfer characteristics can be represented in two different forms, both having three resistors. So you can either construct a T-network or a pi-network of resistors that has the exact same transfer function as the original arbitarily complex circuit of resistors.

So as any network can be reduced into two different basic topologies of three resistors, you cannot in theory determine anything about the original topology.

Answer (score 1):

The theory you're looking for is N-port theory.  In general, at DC, we can only infer a matrix of impedances and transfer gains between ports (external connections to the network plus ground).  Put another way, any arbitrary network of resistors can be simplified to a matrix of them.

At AC, we can infer more about the internal structure, but there are degenerate cases such as pole-zero cancellation, and depending on whether we're talking purely ideal lumped-element networks, or real ones, physical effects like transmission lines and waves.  There is some freedom on how to express such a network, for example ladder vs. lattice topology, and isolation transformers can be applied arbitrarily, so that there is no unique solution but an infinite space of equivalent solutions.

Similarly, for the DC case, there is some freedom, for example the two-port can be expressed as a pi or tee section.

Minimum-phase networks (particularly those forced to be minimum-phase, i.e. the one-port) can additionally be expressed as a series chain of parallel-resonant (RLC) tanks, or a parallel chain of series-resonant tanks.